# Few questions on restoring an os from an image

Tags: backup, operating-systems, restore, disk-image

1. Is it possible to backup and restore more than 1 partition?For example, I have a multi-boot computer. And I want to backup them all(Windows xp, Windows 7, and Ubuntu)
2. If it is possible, what are the applications that offer this kind of feature?
3. Please give me an idea on how this works. If ever its possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of backup program is called disk imaging/cloning which can be likened to taking a snapshot/image of your disk/partition at the point in time at which you take it. Taking an image of a partition means you can later restore this image to another partition. Taking a disk image takes an image of the whole disk, normally including the boot sectors etc (so the bootable part of the disk is preserved).

[Here is more detail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_cloning)

[and  a list of software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_cloning_software)

if you watch out on [GiveAwayofTheDay](http://www.giveawayoftheday.com/) paragon are always giving away a free copy of their tools.

There are also lots of Linux based live cds that can do this, although I have not had much luck with them on Windows partitions.

Comment: Would I also be backing up the spywares and virus in the system if there is one?

Comment: Yup, everything, it is literally an image. What I personally do is have 2 disks one with the OS on it and the other with my data, then if the OS gets mucked up I simply reimage the OS disk and it is back to a nice new state.

Comment: I do the same as Charles. If my PC ever has system problems, I reboot with my "EASEUS Todo Backup" disc installed, and choose to reimage my SSD from my RAID 1 array. 15 minutes later my Windows 7 system is brand spanking new again. Desktop/documents/music/videos all redirect to my data drive, so reimaging doesn't cause me any loss of data. Because the spare "C" image and data all lives on my RAID array, no single disc failure can cause any loss of data.